# Unauthorized page restriction wants a refresh

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting started with ReactJS and I wanted to restrict the sign-in page for not authorized users only and I want to redirect those users to the page they were before after they log in (that part is not working as well).

The problem is that when I log in and then go back to `/sign-in` page, it says that I'm still not authorized, even tho I can literally see the access token in local storage (look at the picture below). However, if I refresh the page, NotAuthorizedRoute works and it redirects me back to home page.

How can I fix this in React? How can I also redirect back to the previously opened page and not `/` only?

In other words, `const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== null;` is being activated only after a page refresh. In angular, I used to fix such things by `@Input`/`@Output` and EventEmitter but I'm new to React and I don't know how to deal with it yet.

Image:
[image]

Login.js

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserService from '../../Services/UserService';

import {
  makeStyles,
  Typography,
  Container,
  TextField,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
  Button,
  Grid,
  CircularProgress
} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  content: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    padding: theme.spacing(8, 0, 6)
  },
  form: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1)
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2)
  }
}));

const Login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const history = useHistory();

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      username,
      password,
    };

    setLoading(true);

    UserService.loginUser(user)
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.token);
        setLoading(false);
        history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className={classes.content}>
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h2" align="center" color="textPrimary" gutterBottom>
            Sign In
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="h5" align="center" color="textSecondary" paragraph>
            If you are not registered, you should sign up.
          </Typography>
        </Container>
      </div>

      <Container maxWidth="md">

        <Grid container justify="center" spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>

            {!UserService.isLoggedIn ?
              <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  type="text"
                  label="Username"
                  value={username}
                  onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                  error={error !== ''}
                  helperText={error}
                />

                <TextField
                  variant="outlined"
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  fullWidth
                  type="password"
                  label="Password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                />

                <FormControlLabel
                  control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                  label="Remember me"
                />

                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  fullWidth
                  variant="contained"
                  color="primary"
                  className={classes.submit}
                  disabled={loading}
                >
                  Sign In
              </Button>
              </form>
              :
              <Grid container justify="center">
                Logged in.
              </Grid>
            }

            {loading &&
              <Grid container justify="center">
                <CircularProgress className={classes.spinner} />
              </Grid>
            }
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotAuthorizedRoute from './Helpers/NotAuthorizedRoute';

import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './Components/Home/Home';
import User from './Components/User/User';
import Login from './Components/Login/Login';

function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/users" component={User} />
          <NotAuthorizedRoute path="/sign-in" component={Login} />
          <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </Switch>

      </Router>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Helpers/NotAuthorizedRoute.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import UserService from '../Services/UserService';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const NotAuthorizedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !UserService.isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
          )
      }
    />
  )
}

export default NotAuthorizedRoute;
```

Service/UserService.js

```js
const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== null;

const loginUser = async (user) => {
  const { username, password } = user;
  if (username === 'qwe' && password === '123') {
    return { token: 'access_token' };
  } else {
    throw new Error('Wrong username or password');
  }
}

export default { isLoggedIn, loginUser };
```

**EDIT:** If I put `!localStorage.getItem('access_token')` instead of `!UserService.isLoggedIn` in `NotAuthorizedRoute`, it works. Why?

Answer (score 0):

In React, the component only re-renders when `props` or `state` changes. In your `NotAuthorizedRoute` you're directly using `isLoggedIn` param from file. Instead, you should pass `isLoggedIn` as prop from parent component. So you can re-write `NotAuthorizedRoute.js` as:

```js
import React from 'react';
import UserService from '../Services/UserService';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const NotAuthorizedRoute = ({ component: Component, isLoggedIn=false, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        !UserService.isLoggedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
          )
      }
    />
  )
}

export default NotAuthorizedRoute;
```

and call this component as

```js
<NotAuthorizedRoute ... isLoggedIn={UserService.isLoggedIn} />
```

Comment: still the same.

Comment: If I do `!localStorage.getItem('access_token')` instead of `!UserService.isLoggedIn` in NotAuthorizedRoute, it works fine. Why?